# strcmp crashes even though both strings are sane

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I have a peculiar problem where my program crashes at strcmp.

Upon gdb core analysis I see that both the strings being checked are sane meaning their pointers are not NULL and they contain finite null terminated values.

However one of the strings is garbage (not the one the variable is intended to contain)

Leaving aside the fact that it is garbage, I really want to know why strcmp would crash for 2 sane strings ? What could be the possible causes of this ?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

An example,

```
a = strcmp(b,c);
(gdb) p b
$92 = 0x7f58d3a36b89 "H\205\300uRH\215}\320\350\a\300\361\377A\276"
(gdb) p c
$93 = 0x2041e48 "MAIN"
```

Comment: please provide an example of where you went wrong or a sample test case proving your point

Comment: It would be nice to see related info from core dump.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is garbage? If it is random bytes then that could cause the issue.

Comment: "Sane" possibly means the pointer is pointing at memory it shouldn't be and you have undefined behaviour and are lucky it crashed. To answer your questions 1. Yes. 2. Deferencing uninitialised pointers, pointers pointing somewhere they shouldn't be, ...

Comment: my guess is the "garbage" is not null terminated, so you are getting seg fault. But this is just a guess, we can't really help unless you show us more info like what both strings contain and how you are calling strcmp...

Comment: The "garbage" string is null terminated as shown in my example. Otherwise gdb wouldn't have printed only that segment.

Comment: The pointer points to memory that your program is not allowed to access. Dereferencing the pointer means: accessing that memory.

Comment: Which part of the memory is my program not allowed to access but gdb is allowed to print ?

Comment: Post the code.  Debugging output can be misleading: `b` and `c` might not be available with their actual values to the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for `b` and `c` *seem* OK, but due to optimizations, especially around such functions as `strcmp()` that may undergo intense macro expansion, the actual values might not be available to the debugger.

The problem might be easy to spot in the source code, you should post the source to the offending function.

The value `0x7f58d3a36b89` printed by `gdb` for variable `b` is surprisingly large!  You could try and modify your code this way:

```
static char bb = *b;
static char cc = *c;
a = strcmp(b, c);
```

Forcing an access to `b` and `c` before the `strcmp()` may move the crash up and let you verify if `b` is indeed what `gdb` prints it to be.

Comment: Sorry, for obvious reasons, I cannot reveal the code as-is since it's closed source. I tried to make do with an example that looks similar. I am looking more for ideas and situations where strcmp can crash even though both the strings being compared are OK. Someone suggests that the pointer is outside of referenceable memory. If that is the case, why can gdb print it ? Shouldn't gdb also complain that address is out of bounds ?

Comment: @Proteen: `gdb` would complain too.  My guess is the debugging information is not precise enough for `gdb` to use you the correct values for `b` and `c`.  You could disassemble the code and see for yourself which register is being used as the address causing the crash.  Without further information, there is not much we can say.  The value printed for `b` is surprisingly large.